# Cannot bind <M-s-left>

Tags: key-bindings

I use `elpy` as Python IDE. I want `M-<left>` and `M-<right>` (M = alt) not to be overridden by elpy with `elpy-nav-indent-shift-left` and `elpy-nav-indent-shift-left` but insted bind these to something else.

Here's what I tried in my `.emacs`:

```
(eval-after-load "elpy"
  '(progn
     (define-key elpy-mode-map (kbd "M-<left>") nil)
     (define-key elpy-mode-map (kbd "M-<right>") nil)
     (define-key elpy-mode-map (kbd "M-s-<left>") (elpy-nav-indent-shift-left))
     (define-key elpy-mode-map (kbd "M-s-<right>") (elpy-nav-indent-shift-right))
     ))
```

`M-<left>` and `M-<right>` now do `left-word` and `right-word` as intended. The other bindings however just yield

```
<M-s-left> is undefined
<M-s-right> is undefined
```

Why is it not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
 (define-key elpy-mode-map (kbd "M-s-<left>") 'elpy-nav-indent-shift-left)
 (define-key elpy-mode-map (kbd "M-s-<right>") 'elpy-nav-indent-shift-right)
```

EDIT: using `use-package` and `bind-keys` one can do the following to get what you are after (might be an overkill if you are not using it yet)

```
(use-package elpy
  :ensure t
  :config
  (unbind-key "M-<left>" elpy-mode-map)
  (unbind-key "M-<right>" elpy-mode-map)
  (bind-keys :map elpy-mode-map
           ("M-s-<left>" . elpy-nav-indent-shift-left)
           ("M-s-<right>" . elpy-nav-indent-shift-right)))
```

Comment: This solved it. I guess in the long run learning some elisp would pay off, even only from a user perspective...

Comment: Learning elisp would certainly pay off. I'm also only a user and would in this case use `use-package` and `bind-keys` which I hope will produce the right thing which was pointed out by @nickd I will update the post, to show what I mean.

Answer (score 5):

`(elpy-nav-indent-shift-left)` is a function *call* in lisp. You want to bind the key to the *function*, but instead you've bound it to whatever the function call returns. The best way IMO (but see @Drew's comment below) to do that is to say `(function <name>)`, so e.g.

```
 (define-key elpy-mode-map (kbd "M-s-<left>") (function elpy-nav-indent-shift-left))
```

There is a reader macro that is equivalent:

```
(define-key elpy-mode-map (kbd "M-s-<left>") #'elpy-nav-indent-shift-left)
```

but most people write the quoted form as in the accepted answer:

```
(define-key elpy-mode-map (kbd "M-s-<left>") 'elpy-nav-indent-shift-left)
```

although the first two forms are (again IMO) preferable. The [Elisp manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Anonymous-Functions) says this:

> -- Special Form: function function-object
>
> ```
> This special form returns FUNCTION-OBJECT without evaluating it.
>  In this, it is similar to ‘quote’ (*note Quoting).  But unlike
>  ‘quote’, it also serves as a note to the Emacs evaluator and
>  byte-compiler that FUNCTION-OBJECT is intended to be used as a
>  function.  Assuming FUNCTION-OBJECT is a valid lambda expression,
>  this has two effects:
>
>    • When the code is byte-compiled, FUNCTION-OBJECT is compiled
>       into a byte-code function object (*note Byte Compilation::).
>
>    • When lexical binding is enabled, FUNCTION-OBJECT is converted
>       into a closure.  *Note Closures::.
> ```
>
> The read syntax ‘#'’ is a short-hand for using ‘function’.  The
>   following forms are all equivalent:
>
> ```
> (lambda (x) (* x x))
> (function (lambda (x) (* x x)))
> #'(lambda (x) (* x x))
> ```

Comment: FWIW, I disagree with your characterization of **The "real" way** to bind a key to a function (a command, actually). There's nothing wrong with using a command symbol in a key-binding function (e.g. `define-key`, `global-set-key`). The byte compiler and the interpreter follow a function symbol to its function. And the Emacs doc itself uses just function symbols - see, e.g., node [Init Rebinding](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-Rebinding.html). But there are other contexts than key binding where it makes sense to prefer `#'`, to tell the compiler about a function.

Comment: (That said, your first two sentences are a good answer.)

Comment: OK - I softened it a bit, but I still think that `#'foo` is "better" than `'foo` even in this case.

Comment: Yes, it certainly doesn't hurt in this case.